# Increase Height of Select Graphs in Subplot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that produces the output below. I would like the same exact output but I want to double the height of the bottom 3 graphs while keeping the size of the top 2 rows of graphs the same. Using my current code as a starting point, is it possible to do so?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
grid= plt.GridSpec(5,4, wspace =0.4, hspace=0.9)

g1 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0:2])
g2 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 2:4])
g3 = plt.subplot(grid[1, 0:2])
g4 = plt.subplot(grid[1, 2:4])
g5 = plt.subplot(grid[2, 0:4])
g6 = plt.subplot(grid[3, 0:4])
g7 = plt.subplot(grid[4, 0:4])

g1.plot(SZ_ED_TOT['Week'], SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_1_2_3'],SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_4_5'])
g1.set_title('SZ Acuity Count')
g1.tick_params(labelrotation=90)
g1.set_ylabel('Patient Count')
g1.set_xlabel('Week')
g1.legend(['ESI_1_2_3', 'ESI_4_5'],
          loc='upper right', frameon=False)

Only included one example of my graph code for post conciseness
```

[image]

Comment: Increase the grid size, then make the bottom ones two rows?

Comment: Ive tried to test that idea on just  the bottom graph but it doenst change the dimensions. grid= plt.GridSpec(6,4, wspace =0.4, hspace=0.9) g7 = plt.subplot(grid[4:5, 0:4]). Any ideas on what your code would look like for that idea?

Comment: `4:5` is the same with `4`. Did you mean/try `4:6`?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the answer:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
grid= plt.GridSpec(8,2, wspace =0.3, hspace=1.7)

g1 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0:1])
g2 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 1:3])
g3 = plt.subplot(grid[1, 0:1])
g4 = plt.subplot(grid[1, 1:3])
g5 = plt.subplot(grid[2:4, 0:3])
g6 = plt.subplot(grid[4:6, 0:3])
g7 = plt.subplot(grid[6:8, 0:3])
```

Comment: `2:4`, `4:6`, `6:8` would be enough.